# ReactNative: TextInput disappear in FlexLayout

Tags: react-native

I'm learning react-native,when I trying to use TextInput component in a flex layout, it disappear .

index.android.js

```
//....
render(){
    return (
        <View style={  {flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput placeholder="test"/>
        </View>
    )
}

//....
```

I was very confused.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to set TextInput's height , but it doesn't work.
And I finally success to set width or {flex:1} to TextInput.
I think, when the parant container been set {flexDirection:"row"}, TextInput's width is 0, so I can't see it. By default,the parent container's flex direction is 'column',TextInput Element adjust itself's {flex:1} to fill the parent container.

Comment: Excellent Explanation. Found the answer after several hours of painful tinkering with flexbox......

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a height on the TextInput:

```
<TextInput placeholder="test" style={{ height:60 }} />
```